# Combine two arrays into one JSON

Tags: python, json

I have array `A["a","b","c"]` and `B[1,2,3]`. I am trying to combine them into a single JSON file that has the following structure

```
[{
    "A": "a",
    "B": 1
  },
  {
    "A": "b",
    "B": 2
  },
  {
    "A": "c",
    "B": 3
  }
]
```

So far I have tried

```
data = {}
data['a'] = A
data['b'] = B
json_data = json.dumps(data)
print(json_data)
```

but that does not produce the result I want.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
a = ["a","b","c"]
b = [1,2,3]
result = [{'A':c, 'B':d} for c, d in zip(a, b)]
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 1}, {'A': 'b', 'B': 2}, {'A': 'c', 'B': 3}]
```

Comment: That works perfect. However, is it possible to be in double quotes not single ?

Comment: @JonDoe The `__repr__` of a string in Python is the value surrounded by single quotes, however, you can use `print(json.dumps(result))` to produce a string where each key is surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did it.